# Notification for review tasks, "first post"

Tags: feature-request, review, notifications, new-users, feed

I was wandering if there is an efficient way to get an **instantaneous notification for pending review tasks**.

I'm aware of Chrome extensions "[Desktop Notifications for Stack Exchange](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/desktop-notifications-for/ijglncoabcgieiokjmgdogpefdblmnle)", that's the kind of solution I would like to have, but this particular extension is for messages only. Probably something based on Mathematica, Python, but I don't see events specific for review tasks on [Stack Exchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com). Probably an RSS feed?

In particular, I would like to track [first posts tasks by new users at Mathematica.SE](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/review).

If there is not, then I think it would be a desirable feature.

Comment: Userscripts. Found [one rough example](http://stackapps.com/questions/4086/review-stalker-user-script), likely there are others.